# Represent drop down menu of QPushButton with Qt Style Sheet?

Tags: qt4, qtstylesheets

I'm wondering which is a proper way for representing the menu dropped down from a QPushButton ?

> QPushButton::drop-down { blabla }

doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the menu for a `QPushButton` using `setMenu()`, the menu continues to exist as its own entity so you would target the `QMenu` object itself with an appropriate selector. A `QMenu` supports the box model. Some example styling can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu).

Answer (score 1):

In QT Style Sheets, you can style widgets that are members of other widgets like so:

```
QPushButton QMenu
{
    /* blahblah */
}
```

Where QPushButton is the parent widget, and QMenu is the child. It also works for other stylable items and pseudo-states, for example

```
QPushButton QMenu::separator
{
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightGray;
    background: #5A5A5A;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
```